# how to prove $P=M$?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $P$ be an open submanifold of a Riemannian manifold $M$. If $P$ is complete and $M$ is connected, Then the conclusion is $P=M$.

I have no idea to prove this result, please help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: What is the closure of $P$?

Answer (score 3):

$P$ is a complete subspace of a metric space, so it is closed. Since we assume it's also open, and since $M$ is connected, either $P = \varnothing$ of $P = M$.

Comment: Is the empty set considered a submanifold?

Comment: Yes. The definition of a submanifold typically starts with "every point of $P$ has a neighborhood such that..." which is vacuously true.

Comment: P is assumed to be geodesically complete, not complete in the metric sense.

Comment: @PedroGomes Says who?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi         This exercise is taken from O'Neil, and he had not proven any Hopf Rinow theorem in chapter 3, where this exercises features. So, completeness in the metric sense is not implied, he defines completeness in the geodesic sense. So this needs another proof.

Comment: @PedroGomes How do you know this is the same exercise? OP doesn't say anything about geodesics.

Comment: The way the question is framed plus the terminology and the fact that it's complete in the metric sense is too straightforward.